# retrieving Date or time from Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, datetime

In SQLite DB I m saving time as `datetime('now')` which as expected saving the time in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS` format. 
Now I want to retrieve time from that row in `DD-MMM HH:MM` format.
Is there any straight way of doing this?
Please Help.
Thanks.

Sample Code:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO SessionInfo VALUES (00,'Demo Session',10,'Complete',7,datetime('now'),'"+usr_email+"');");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO SessionInfo VALUES (01,'Demo Session',18,'Complete',8,datetime('now'),'"+usr_email+"');");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO SessionInfo VALUES (02,'Demo Session',40,'Complete',4,datetime('now'),'"+usr_email+"');");
```

i want to retrieve data from any one row and the time should be in `DD-MMM HH:MM` format.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has the [strftime() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), but there is no `MMM` format (whatever that may mean).

You should format dates in your application.